# Monster can´t resolve to a variable

Tags: javascript, java, spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Random random = new Random();
int monster = random.nextInt(5);

```
if (String.valueOf(monster).equals("3"));
System.out.println("Um dragão enorme aparceu!"); } 

else if (String.valueOf(monster).equals("2"));
System.out.println("Um lobo selvagem apareceu!") 
    }
```

on the second onde (else if), ECLIPSE says that i can´t resolve monser to a variable, but on the first one was perferct.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line doesn't have an { (it has a `;`, which you don't want to put after an if!).

So, take the `;`, remove it. Then replace that with a `{`.

Answer (score 0):

The `;` after the `if`, makes the if does nothing.

Since you didn't open a `{` after the `if`, the `}` will close the previous `{` (probably was closing the function.

Solution: replace the `;` at the end of the `if` by `{`

Also, you have a performance issue:

The `monster` it's an `int`, and you don't need to convert it to `String`.

please replace `String.valueOf(monster).equals("3")`

by:`monster == 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Random random = new Random(); int monster = random.nextInt(5);
    if (String.valueOf(monster).equals("3")) {
    System.out.println("Um dragão enorme aparceu!"); } 

    else if (String.valueOf(monster).equals("2")) {
    System.out.println("Um lobo selvagem apareceu!");
    }
```

**if and else statements never end with ;**